# Eclipse-like formatting for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-formatting

Is there a tool for Visual Studio that will automatically format source code (C#) on saving it?  This would be useful for my multi-developer team to keep the code looking uniform, especially before the code is checked into the source control repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CodeRush or ReSharper come to mind.

Comment: specifically there's this Dx_FormatOnSave plugin for DevExpress: http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2010/04/13/dx_formatonsave-format-documents-in-visual-studio-when-you-save.aspx

Answer (score 1):

PowerCommands for Visual Studio: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands

If you install the addin and look for PowerCommands under the Tools->Options menu, there's two tick boxes for "Format document on save" and "Remove and Sort Usings on save". It's one of my favourite addins for that exact functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Many (and me) use [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) and set it to analyse files on a build and I set it to flag warnings as errors so issues must be resolved prior to a successful build.

I prefer this method as obfuscating the responsibility to a third party which automatically styles the code without developer intervention I feel loses something, over reliance on this method could lead to a developers code becoming worse and worse without them even knowing it.

It seems more preferable that the developer be notified of issues and forced to fix them, so as to hopefully overall improve their coding skills.

EDIT: I know this is an old post I just thought my thoughts could be helpful to somebody happenning accross this page.